# Determine correct column in dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to remap some data for an export. The data is being pulled from multiple tables as a view.

In the view the pertinent columns and example values are:

```
size_bucket    size_desc
     2             XS
     3             S
     4             M
     5             L
     6             XL
```

Size bucket corresponds to a column in another table that contains the various size descriptions; for example:

```
size02    size03    size04    size05    size06
  XS         S        M         L          XL
```

The problem is that for the export, the values of size_bucket are incorrect and don't correspond to the related sizexx column in the other table. So I have a table with the correct mappings that contain the correct values for the various sizexx columns.

What I need to do is get determine which column contains the correct value and switch out the value of size_bucket to be the correct corresponding sizexx column.

So the correct values in the mapping table I have are

```
size02    size03    size04    size05    size06    size07
  XXS       XS        S          M        L         XL
```

Finally, here would be a sample psuedo query I'm trying to create to get the correct values for size_bucket:

```
SELECT  
      CASE (u.sizebucket)
         WHEN '1' THEN u.sizebucket 
         WHEN '2' THEN 
             CASE WHEN u.size_desc = k.size02 THEN '2' END
             CASE WHEN u.size_desc = k.size03 THEN '3' END
             /* and so on for all the different sizexx columns */
         WHEN '3' THEN 
             /* REPEAT ABOVE CODE */
         /* REPEAT WHEN FOR ALL SIZES */
       END AS size_bucket,
       k.size_name, u.size_desc, k.size01, k.size02, k.size03, k.size04, 
       k.size05, k.size06, k.size07, k.size08, k.size09, k.size10, k.size11, 
       k.size12, k.size13, k.size14, k.size15
FROM ExportView u
INNER JOIN size_map_table k ON u.Size_Code = k.size_code
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how to do this in a much simpler way would be greatly appreciated. I'm not even sure yet if the way I have in mind to do it here would even work yet.

Here is some data examples per your request:

For the view all columns are nvarchar, likewise in the mapping table.

Some sample data in the view:

```
size_code    size_desc    size_bucket
   LDS          XS             3
   LDS           S             4
   LDS           M             5
   LDN           0             2
   LDN           2             3
   LDN           4             4
```

In the mapping table:

```
size_code    size01    size02    size03    size04    size05
   LDS                   XS
   LDS                              S
   LDS                                       M
   LDN         0
   LDN                   2
   LDN                              4
```

Expected results would be to correct the values for `size_bucket` like this:

```
size_code    size_desc    size_bucket
   LDS          XS             2
   LDS           S             3
   LDS           M             4
   LDN           0             1
   LDN           2             2
   LDN           4             3
```

Comment: How about some ddl and sample data in addition to the desired output. We can't really help much here because we have no idea what your data looks like. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: For the view all columns are nvarchar, likewise in the mapping table.

Some sample data in the view:

Ooops, hit enter. Editing...

Comment: ok, just add expected results, please

Comment: I'll leave this as a reminder and come back later, but I still not sure to undertand your request. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0420e/1

Comment: This is still not exactly clear but couldn't you just use size_bucket - 1? That would work at least on the basic sample you posted.

Comment: No I can't. The values for size_bucket correspond to the size01, size02, size03, etc columns. The problem is that the values in size_bucket are incorrect for the data export, and the mapping table contains the correct values for size_desc in the various size01, size02, etc columns. So what I need to do is determine which of those size00 columns in the mapping table contain the matching size_desc and update the value for size_bucket accordingly.

Does that explain it a little better?

Comment: Just to add a little more detail, in the examples I gave, the size_bucket values are off by 1, but this may not always be the case, so size_bucket - 1 won't work. I wish it were that simple!  :-)